# R - Graphing data.frame with multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Problem:**
I have a dataframe that I constructed so I could create a graph that looks like this. 
[image]

Essentially I want to have a boundary, and then some lines down the middle.

I am having trouble understanding how to do this. I have gone through a few tutorials but could use some specific help.

**Data**
[image]

I have the most basic graph built, but I do not see the path forward.

```
p <- ggplot(geomean.build.time.by.user)
p + geom_line(aes(x = week, y = user_geomean_build_time), stat = "smooth", method = "loess")
```

[image]

Comment: See `?geom_ribbon`.

Comment: You could also use `geom_smooth()` instead of `geom_line` with `stat = 'smooth'`. The default will be a loess smoothed line with confidence interval plotted as a ribbon.

Comment: @Gregor I will look into geom_ribbon. I have tried both approaches. I don't think my data makes a big difference on those either way.

Comment: There was a response to [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154346/fitted-confidence-intervals-forecast-function-r) about plotting prediction intervals that may be applicable.  It uses base R to plot lines and bands and should do what you want.

Comment: @Barker thanks. I will mess around with that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I put together a very basic graph. Nothing fancy. I am just trying to determine if there is value in this data.

```
p <- ggplot(geomean.build.time.by.user)
p + geom_line(aes(x = week, y = user_geomean_build_time), stat = "smooth", method = "loess", colour = "#00DCFF", size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(x = week, y = proj_geomean_build_time), colour = "#E85831", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
geom_line(aes(x = week, y = user_geomean_bt_plus_sd), colour = "#0ED26E", size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(x = week, y = user_geomean_bt_minus_sd), colour = "#0ED26E", size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(x = week, y = proj_geomean_bt_plus_sd), colour = "#00695D", size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(x = week, y = proj_geomean_bt_minus_sd), colour = "#00695D", size = 2)
```

EDIT

I took the advice and changed to ribbons. overall it looks better, but it doesn't give me the view I was hoping for.

```
p <- ggplot(geomean.build.time.by.user)
p + geom_line(aes(x = week, y = user_geomean_build_time)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = proj_geomean_bt_minus_sd, ymax =proj_geomean_bt_plus_sd, x = week, fill = "avg org build time +/- sd")) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = user_geomean_bt_minus_sd, ymax = user_geomean_bt_plus_sd, x = week, fill = "avg dev build time +/- sd")) +
geom_line(aes(x = week, y = user_geomean_build_time), stat = "smooth", method = "loess", colour = "#F2F2F2", size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(x = week, y = proj_geomean_build_time), colour = "#F20404", linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
```

Comment: Seems like you might want to use `geom_ribbon` to make the two envelopes, using one of the "...plus_sd" as the `ymax`  and "...minus_sd" as the `ymin`.